# What song is playing in episode 22 (s2ep10) of Tokyo Ghoul?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

It's playing between 6:36 and 7:46. I've heard it multiple times in TG itself but couldn't find it on soundtrack, and many times elsewhere. I have a feeling it's somewhat popular

Comment: I couldn't find it but you can try looking at Disk 1/2:                        Disk 1: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbouo2X8egpLA_H-ScT14vbquKu7AUTHR
                               Disk 2: "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbouo2X8egpLunT1OwJmPxgWcP6iyyTCK

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's Augenbinde, or a softer version of it, which I think is the 11th track on disk one.